# JSP- проблема с out.println . JSP не видит его

Tags: jsp

Есть проблема небольшая при запуске цикла в скриплете не видит метод out.println() толька видит его с System.out.println() . НО мне просто нужно вивести результута что скопилировался в цикле на страницу .
Помогите пж)

````
<body>

<% for(int i =0; i<=5; i++) {
  не работает->  out.println("Number of clothes is " + i);
%>
<body>
<html> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема. Попробуйте добавить в pom.xml следующую зависимость:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: ок попробую большое спасибо